# sequence diagram used as a use case

Tags: uml, diagrams

Has anyone ever seen a sequence diagram used as a use case? I never have and it really twists my head. At my current company, in all the documentation and discussions, the term "use case" is used to label a sequence diagram. I've asked a couple of times about this practice and get funny looks like it is a normal thing to do. - I've been a software engineer for a long time and used UML since the late 1990's when it was first (fairly) widely talked about. I don't expect to change the company culture. I'm just asking if this practice is used anywhere else and associated comments. - Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my university, we learned that a use case diagram and a sequence diagram are both different diagrams with different meanings. In my experience, I have never heard anyone calling a sequence diagram a use case diagram or vice versa so I guess it's just the company culture...

Comment: That's the way I learned it too and have practiced it. That is why this is so odd what I'm seeing now.

Answer (score 0):

Sequence Diagrams are typically used to describe an example of an action flow with communication. Thus Sequence Diagrams are very well suited to display an example for a use case. For this reason it is normal to refer to such a diagram as "a use case".

In consequence you would draw multiple Sequence Diagrams for each Use Case